# Dagger2: Compile error: cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor or from an @Provides-annotated method

Tags: android, mvvm, data-binding, dependency-injection, dagger-2

I am working on Dagger2. I am planning to have same architecture defined in [this](https://github.com/MindorksOpenSource/android-mvvm-architecture) project. I am getting below error.

```
Error:(34, 8) error: [dagger.android.AndroidInjector.inject(T)]      
com.xyz.db.DBHelper cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor or
from an @Provides-annotated method.
com.xyz.data.local.db.DBHelper is injected at
com.xyz.data.local.db.PatientDatabase.<init>(…, dbHelper, …)
com.xyz.data.local.db.PatientDatabase is injected at
com.xyz.di.module.AppModule.provideDataManager(patientDatabase)
com.xyz.data.DataManager is injected at
com.xyz.ui.main.MainActivityModule.provideMainViewModel(dataManager)
com.xyz.ui.main.MainViewModel is injected at                               
com.ccmpat.patient.ui.main.MainActivityModule.mainViewModelProvider (mainViewModel)
android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.Factory is injected at
com.xyz.ui.main.MainActivity.mViewModelFactory
com.xyz.ui.main.MainActivity is injected at
dagger.android.AndroidInjector.inject(arg0)
```

However, AppModule .java already uses @Provides annotation/

```
@Module
public class AppModule {
      @Provides
      @Singleton
      DataManager provideDataManager(PatientDatabase patientDatabase) {
         return patientDatabase;
      }
}
```

My AppComponent.java looks like

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {AndroidInjectionModule.class, AppModule.class, ActivityBuilder.class, NetworkModule.class})
public interface AppComponent {

void inject(PatientApplication app);

@Component.Builder
interface Builder {

    @BindsInstance
    Builder application(Application application);

    AppComponent build();
  }
}
```

PatientDatabase.java looks like,

```
@Singleton
public class PatientDatabase implements DataManager {
  private final Context mContext;
  private final DBHelper mDBDbHelper;
  private final PreferenceHelper mPreferencesHelper;

  @Inject
  public PatientDatabase(Context context, DBHelper dbHelper, PreferenceHelper preferenceHelper) {
    mContext = context;
    mDBDbHelper = dbHelper;
    mPreferencesHelper = preferenceHelper;
  }
}
```

My DBHelper.java simply extends `OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper`

I have googled and found couple of solution to use @Provider in AppModule .java with reference and I found its already there.

Am I missing anything?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your component does not know where to get DBHelper since no one provides it. Notice that you have a provider for `DataManager` that requires an instance of `PatientDatabase`. `PatientDatabase` is annotated with `@Inject` in constructor so it is added to the graph. But the problem lies in the dependencies of the `PatientDatabase`. To solve your problem, you should also provide your dbHelper and preferenceHelper instance in the module.

Try adding this to your module

```
@Provides
DBHelper provideDbHelper() {
   return new DBHelper();
}

@Provides
PreferenceHelper providePreferenceHelper() {
   return new PreferenceHelper();
}
```

If you have a factory, simply replace the `new` with the instantiation. If you have an existing instance that you want to use, pass it to the module upon creation.

Comment: Thank you. It worked. PreferenceHelper was already exist but not the DBHelper. I will make sure to add everything that we @inject to AppModule.java. Again thanks.